# How to make colorful "flash" particles in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When i use the command `/particle minecraft:flash ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0 3`, it creates a white explosion, but firework explosions give the colorful version of the same particle. How do i colour it? Is it some kind of a hidden argument?

Comment: See if [this video](https://youtu.be/AL9z70mMb84?t=246) is helpful. I added the start time tag to where they're modifying color. Only drawback is that they aren't working with the flash particle. Let me know if it solves the problem so I can summarize it for future readers as an answer. I'd test it myself, but I only have bedrock edition.

Comment: I already knew that. Dust particles have arguments for colour and size, but only they. I think you can colour other particles only by using a plugin.

Comment: Fair enough :) again, I only have bedrock and no one had even commented, so I spent some time looking around to stumble across that. Best of luck!